# How to remove the wall plate behind Honeywell thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I'm trying to install a smart thermostat. I have a Honeywell programmable thermostat now. However, I found that there's a wall plate in back of the back plate, and it's secured to the wall (not by screws) and I don't know how to remove it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to search on Google and YouTube, but I didn't find anyone who has the same problem. I'm guessing this is a non-typical setup?

Any idea about how to remove this wall plate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The back plate was meant to be held on by screws into the plastic anchors visible on one of the photos.

If the screws are out and the plate is still attached to the wall, it is likely that paint or compound are holding it on.

Try scoring around the edges with a utility knife, then slipping a putty/taping knife behind the plate and prying it off. There may be some minor cosmetic damage to the drywall or paint.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. I noticed that the paint covers the edge of the plate, so it's likely you're right. I'll try again within 2-3 days and update here.

Comment: I think the answer is right. However, we decided to hover Nest back plate over Honeywell back plate, and use screws to tap into the Honeywell plate and the wood.

Comment: Plates are mostly cosmetic, although they do reduce small drafts that may come through some wall. If the fit is close, sounds like a fine solution.